expo-camera/next crashing in android
I am trying to implement the expo-camera/next, it works almost good in iOS but android is just crashing. I think I am missing something or, somehow not grasping the permissions properly. Could someone give me a hand?

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { AutoFocus, useCameraPermissions, CameraView } from "expo-camera/next";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Modal, Alert, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, NativeModules, ActivityIndicator, Keyboard, ScrollView, Vibration, Platform } from 'react-native'


export default function ModalQRCodeScanner({ modalFlag = false, setModalFlag }) {

    const cameraRef = useRef(null);

    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
    const [patient, setPatient] = useState("")
    const [validationData, setValidationData] = useState({
        Into: false,
        Medical: false,
        GDPR: false,
        Physical: false,
    })
    const [modalBirhtdate, setModalBirhtdate] = useState(false)
    const ref = useRef()
    const ref2 = useRef()

    const [permission, requestPermission] = useCameraPermissions();


    if (!permission) {
        // Camera permissions are still loading
        requestPermission()
        return <View />;
      }
    
      if (!permission.granted ) {
        // Camera permissions are not granted yet
        return <View />
      }


   
    return (
        <>
            {/* {modalAppointment && <ModalCreateAppointment visible={modalAppointment} setVisible={setModalAppointment} digi={patient} />} */}

            <Modal
                visible={modalFlag}
                presentationStyle='pageSheet'
                animationType='slide'
                onRequestClose={() => {
                    setModalFlag(false);
                    setScanned(false)
                    setTab("camera")
                }
                }
            >
                <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <View style={{ position: "relative", width: "100%", height: "100%", }}>
                        {tab === "camera" &&
                            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                
                                <CameraView
                                    ref={cameraRef}

                                    onBarcodeScanned={scanned ? console.log("scanned") : handleBarCodeScanned}
                                    barcodeScannerSettings={{
                                        barcodeTypes: ["qr"],
                                    }}

                                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                                /> 
                                <View style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>

                                    <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", flex: 1 }}>
                                        <View style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "#fff", height: 250, width: 250 }}></View>
                                        <Text style={{ marginTop: 20, fontSize: 20, color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>{t("ModalQRScanner_scanqrcodefrom")} {"\n"} {t("ModalQRScanner_patientcw1medux")}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end", paddingBottom: 50 }}>

                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => closePopUp()}>
                                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "white" }}>{t("ModalAddPatient_close")}</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        }



PS of course I shorten the code quite a lot so that you don't have to read through many lines of things related to medical stuff.

Were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same exact issue. The scanner works fine on iOS but keeps crashing on Android.

@HamedJimoh partly yes. To be honest don't know what I have done but it works in some androids and others not. But I read on expo forum that they were about to release a stable version of expo-camera/next for both platforms.
